# Shell script to change index value

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file that reads

```
96826999, words
96826321, wotds
96826567, dsdsa
96826455,dssdsd
```

I want to change all number in the first column to be sequential starting at 96826700
so the file ends up looking like

```
96826700, words
96826701, wotds
96826702, dsdsa
96826703, dssdsd
```

Belowis the shell script I'm trying to use but I'm missing something can you help?

```
INDEX=96826700
for i in `cat file`
do
sed 's/^968267[0-9]/'${INDEX}'/g'
INDEX=INDEX +1
done
```

Comment: `INDEX=INDEX`? Better double-check that... :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use bash shell (or ksh) without external commands

```
#!/bin/bash    
# tested on bash 4.
IFS="," read a b < file
while IFS="," read x b
do
    ((a++))
    echo "$a,$b"
done < file
```

Comment: +1, thanks for this, but isn't it `while IFS="," read a b` instead of `while IFS="," read x b`?

Comment: @Alberto, no, `$a` is used to count and its value is gotten from the first statement. `x` is just a dummy. We don't want to overwrite `$a`  with what is in the first column in the file. What we only want to get is `$b` and the incremented `$a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk  -F"," 'NR==1{count=$1}{count++;print count"," $2}' temp
```

Comment: Its better not to hardcode the count. `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}NR==1{count=$1}{print ++count,$2}' temp`

Comment: Yes you are right.i thought the OP wants the start  number hard coded.